# Rails 5: refresh partial in another partial with AJAX update action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have */views/layouts/_navigation.html.erb* where User Profile partial is generated:

```
<nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav metismenu" id="side-menu">
<!-- Here we render user profile -->
      <div id='userprofile'>
        <%= render 'layouts/userprofile' %>
      </div>
<!-- Here we render menu -->
        <% cache "#{I18n.locale}_menu" do %>
          <%= render 'layouts/menu' %>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- Here we render modal window dialog -->
<%= render 'users/dialog' %>
```

In */views/layouts/_userprofile.html.erb* I have this:

```
<div class="dropdown profile-element">
    <span>
      <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="<%= image_url 'profile_small.jpg' %>"/>
    </span>
      <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
        <span class="clear">
          <span class="block m-t-xs">
            <strong class="font-bold"><%= current_user.name %></strong><b class="caret"></b>
          </span>
        </span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInRight m-t-xs">
        <li><a href=""><%= t('.sellerdash') %></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><%= t('.buyerdash') %></a></li>
        <li><%= link_to t('.profile'), current_user %></li>
        <li><%= link_to t('.settings'), edit_user_path(current_user), remote: true %></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><%= link_to t('.logout'), logout_path %></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

When Settings is clicked, modal window is opened and User Settings can be edited. There is */views/users/update.js.erb* which does same job, but in User table:

```
$('#dialog').modal('toggle');
$('#user_<%= @user.id %>').replaceWith('<%= j render (@user) %>')
```

**When user settings is updated, I'd like to refresh `_userprofile.html.erb` partial in order to display new info, e.g., User Name.**

So far I was thinking I need to add this line to */views/users/update.js.erb*

```
$('#userprofile').html('<%= j render 'layouts/userprofile', locals: {user: @user} %>')
```

however it is not working.

**How do I fix this, please? Thank you!**

**Update**

Update action in my /controllers/users_controller.rb looks like this:

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
        if @user.update(user_params)
          format.json { head :no_content }
          format.js
        else
          format.json { render json: @user.errors.full_messages,
                                     status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
  end
```

I've found out `userprofile.html.erb` refreshes only after second trial in a row. Basically it does not refresh first time and in secound round it refreshes value which had to be rendered in first round. Some strange behaviour. **Does anyone have an idea what's going on with my partials?**

Answer (score 1):

As a first measure i would first check that the request gets triggered as JS. You can check that in console

Also beware of using single quotes all over the javascript code

```
$('#userprofile').html("<%= j render 'layouts/userprofile', locals: {user: @user} %>")
```

notice the double quotes i added

Also i assume you have in your controller

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

in that case there is no need to pass locals as they can be directly accessible to the partial

so the code becomes

```
$('#userprofile').html("<%= j render 'layouts/userprofile' %>")
```

Also make sure in console you do not see any errors. Javascript requests do not crash the front-end usually so you won't see an error on screen.

Hope these help

Comment: Thank you. I see ` Rendered layouts/_userprofile.html.erb (23.9ms)` in console, however new value is not displayed. I have `format.js` in controller. Basically new value is saved, but not rendered. Can it be Rails somehow does not understand it has to replace value in `<div id='userprofile'>`?

Comment: i should make myself more clear, what you care is not "rendered..." but e.g "Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML" you see the last part it says HTML, so verify that for you it says JS instead. Also can you post the controller action code as well?

Comment: In console I see `Processing by UsersController#update as JS`
Please, see Users controller code for Update action added above.

Comment: Here is what I have found. On first Update, value is not changed, but when I do second Update in a row, it updates to the value which should have been updated in first attempt. I believe this means Rails understand what to update, it's just not updating right way.

Comment: Its possible there is some sort of error the first time, you do you show the errors with this line, does it work? (`format.json { render json: @user.errors.full_messages,
                                     status: :unprocessable_entity }`)

Comment: Yes, that error line works as I see it throwing out something. Maybe the problem is because I have this `<%= render 'layouts/userprofile' %>` line in _navigation.html.erb partial?

Comment: Hmm that should be fine. Question you say that settings opens modal but i see that you go somewhere else instead (edit_user_path) with a remote: true flag. As far as i know modals open without going to a specific page first. What is your implementation on that?

Comment: Well, I implemented [AJAX Bootstrap Modals from here](http://www.benkirane.ch/ajax-bootstrap-modals-rails/) The thing is I'd like to add extra functionality to `update.js.erb` so it updates that `_userprofile.html.erb` partial and user profile value refreshes. Do you think I could achieve that differently?